Steping Vgs threshold of a MOSFET spice model?
Hi I'm wondering if it is legit to step the spice variable VTO to simulate the different threshold of a device?

Yes it is.  You can step any parameter.  And most spice models don't vary their parameters with temperature or simple process variation, so yep, go for it.

@user103776 Can you be more specific?

Similar, but related. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/724485/how-to-i-add-tolerance-to-an-ltspice-lib-electrical-characteristic/724527#724527
